# Transcribe language switcher only showing one language

Tags: transcribe

Transcribe language switcher is only showing English even though I have 2 other languages enabled. I am using this code directly from the docs with minor changes

```
                        {exp:transcribe:language_links show_all="yes"}
                    <ul class="pull-right list-inline">
                        <li>{exp:transcribe:replace name="select_language"}</li>

                        {languages}
                            <li><a href="{link}" class="{if current}active {/if}text-uppercase">{abbreviation}</a></li>
                        {/languages}
                    </ul>
                {/exp:transcribe:language_links}
```

Only shows EN :( should show EN DE ZH. Anyone ever run into this?

Answer (score 1):

The language switcher will not show the additional languages until you save a variable set. In transcribe go to variables and change to another language and add at least one variable and save. Your language will now show in the switcher :)